# Where and how should I define OpenVPN user pass?

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, linux-networking, ubuntu-18.04

Due to this [link](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/using-alternative-authentication-methods/) for having the user/pass authentication the line below should be added to server config file.

```
plugin /usr/share/openvpn/plugin/lib/openvpn-auth-pam.so login
```

But the link doesn't mention that how the file `login` should be filled.
I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PAM stands for a *Pluggable Authentication Modules*, is a system authentication and authorization framework. It could use file, database, whatever you had configured as a password storage. It can even use things other than passwords to authenticate (say, OTP and so on); it can do two-factor authentication, link to external trusted third party (like Kerberos)  and so on. In the simplest case it uses a *shadow* file to store encrypted passwords for system users.

`openvpn-auth-pam` module allows you to authenticate OpenVPN peers using this system authentication framework. `login` here means the PAM service your OpenVPN will use. Likely you already have some services, like `system-auth` is used for local users. Take a look into `/etc/pam.d/` files to have a feel how PAM is configured and also please read its manuals.

What you'll find out is that the `login` service by default just refers to the `system-auth`. To use this as is you first create local system users and set their passwords. Then, add an `--auth-user-pass` option to the client configs, either with credentials file name or naked (then it will ask for credentials interactively). See `man openvpn` for details.

Finally, remember to always employ certificate-based authentication first. Each VPN peer must have its own unique certificate/key pair. The username/password authentication must be considered only as a supplementary security measure. And better don't use `duplicate-cn' feature.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot.

Comment: How can I use it to check whether the username matches the password from a file ?

Comment: Server config must require username/password somehow, for example it might invoke this plugin; client config uses `--auth-user-pass` option to specify credentials file or to ask it interactively. Please, read `man openvpn`, it is definitive guide how to configure it. Also, I strongly suggest to use username/password authentication only as a supplementary security measure; the main security measure must be a certificate-based auth, where each client is securely provided with its own key/certificate pair. And never ever use that `duplicate-cn` crap.